# Como obtener los datos de la fila de una tabla al hacer click en un boton. React

Tags: reactjs, tablas, redux

Estoy tratando de poder obtener los datos de la fila de una tabla cuando haga click en el boton de editar. Especificamente que obtenga unicamente los datos de la fila seleccionada.

Como podria hacer eso ?

**Aqui renderizo la tabla**

```
<table className="table table-dark table-striped table-hover table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th style={{ width: 100 }}>ID</th>
            <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Nombre</th>
            <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Precio</th>
            <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Stock</th>
            <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Proveedor</th>
            <th style={{ width: 150 }}>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {body && body.map( b =>    
            <tr key={b.id}>
                <td>{b.id}</td>
                <td>{b.nombre}</td>
                <td>{b.precio}</td>
                <td>{b.stock}</td>
                <td>{b.proveedor.nombre}</td>
                <td>
                    <button 
                        className="btn btn-info btn-sm"
                        onClick={ handleActua }
                        >
                        Editar
                    </button>
                    &nbsp;
                    <button className="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Eliminar</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        )}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

La data la obtengo de una base de datos y esta se almacena en el store de redux.

[image: Asi es como se ve la tabla]

Asi es como se ve la tabla, cuando agregue mas campos quiero poder seleccionar uno y poder editarlo. Pero no encuentro la manera de poder obtener los datos de las filas al hacer el click.

Espero alguien pueda ayudarme y gracias desde ya por tomarse el tiempo de leer el post.

**PD:** La tabla esta hecha con bootstrap

Comment: Si ya estás llamando a la función `handleActua` desde el botón Editar, ¿por qué no pasarle como argumento los datos de la fila así `onClick={ () => handleActua(b) }`? De esa forma podrías manejar esos datos desde la función. No sé si es eso lo que buscas, o si necesitas hacer algo más.

Comment: @Desarrollos-Web-Urquiza Eso es exactamente lo que queria, me estaba complicando intentando de extraerlos de otra formas, muchas gracias por la ayuda bro.

Comment: Ok, entonces lo agrego como respuesta.

Comment: Si bro, agregala y la marco como respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para poder obtener los datos de uno de los elementos que se están iterando desde un array dentro de un `.map`, es necesario pasar el elemento como argumento a la función en la que necesitas accederlos.

En este caso sería simplemente así:

`onClick={ () => handleActua(b) }`